# inserting HTML with PDO

Tags: php, variables, pdo

I am currently undergoing the process to convert my code from MySQL to PDO however I am having an issue passing a variable. I have edited the content of the variable to give you an idea of exactly what is happening.

```
$status = 'Pending';
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO  
cusbuilder_sites(userid,name,imgurl,url,explain,status,incustom) VALUES  
(:userid,:campname,:imgurl,:targeturl,:explain,:status,:incustom)");

$explain = '<p>Testing Input</p>';
$stmt->bindParam(':userid', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':campname', $_POST['campname']);
$stmt->bindParam(':imgurl', $_POST['imgurl']);
$stmt->bindParam(':targeturl', $_POST['targeturl']);
$stmt->bindValue(':explain', $explain, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $status);
$stmt->bindParam(':incustom', $_POST['incustom']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Now this is the error I am getting:

: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'explain,status,incustom) VALUES ('myuserid','testing12','http://testingsite.com' at line 1'

As you can see the $explain variable contains HTML code and when I remove the p tags it works fine but I need it to actually store the HTML in the database as it did with MySQL.

I have read the answers to this question and have checked if magic_quotes or gpc are enabled. They aren't. In my previous code I was using mysql_real_escape_string which obviously I cannot use in PDO so I just want to know how do i pass HTML in a variable and insert it into a database using PDO?

For those who are going to answer 'use bindValue instead of bindParam' you will see I have already done this and the error is the same.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't have anything to do with HTML.  The SQL query itself is invalid.  `explain` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).  Enclose your identifiers in back-ticks (assuming MySQL, other characters may be used by other databases) to specify them as identifiers:

```
INSERT INTO `cusbuilder_sites`
  (`userid`,`name`,`imgurl`,`url`,`explain`,`status`,`incustom`) VALUES  
  (:userid,:campname,:imgurl,:targeturl,:explain,:status,:incustom)
```

Comment: Getting another error now: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`userid`,`name`,`imgurl`,`url`,`explain`,`status`,`incustom`) VALUES ('myuserid' at line 1'

(the error has backticks in it now)

Comment: all the code is above. The userid is already assigned and the POST variables are part of the form however I did mention that if i take 'explain' out it works so there is no problem with the form but just in case:

`<dd style="width: 550px;"><textarea id="explain" name="explain" class="ckeditor"></textarea></dd>`

This is why i need it to submit HTML because it uses the CKeditor.

Comment: @jay32mcr: `"all the code is above"` - The code in the question doesn't take into account the fact that `explain` is a reserved word.  That's the cause of the error in the question.  Nothing to do with HTML.

Comment: the database is the same as the one used with MySQL for the last 2 years and 'explain' has always been the column name with no issues.

Comment: Simple test would be to put backtick round the column name `explain` and if it runs. Problem solved and case proven

Comment: @RiggsFolly Didn't we just do that with the code shared by david?

Comment: It sounded from your comment like you were saying you did not think that was the answer and you did not want to try it

Comment: @jay32mcr: Did we?  There seems to be a lot more discussion about why it wasn't broken before than about whether or not it's been corrected.  So far there doesn't seem to be any actual attempt to apply the answer and see if it corrects the problem.

Comment: Fixed it by keeping all backticked except userid. Don't ask me how that actually fixed anything but now it works lol.

Comment: The answer explicitly explains ___why it fixed it___

Comment: How so? The answer shows all names backticked which I tried but then it wasn't even passing the whole content of 1 variable as shown in the error but then taking the backtick out of userid  and leaving the rest backticked is no answer to why it worked.